# Simple android chat

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте. Нужно реализовать простой чат между двумя людьми. это по-ходу будет клиент-сервер-клиент.

1) Как делать проверку человек написал что-то или нет? Когда человек пишет: как в скайпе или вконтакте чтоб было видно что человек сейчас пишет или ничего не делает.

2) как проверить прочитал человек сообщение или нет?

Если нет примера кода, то хотя бы подскажите концепцию.

Как я это вижу: создать какой-то сервис в бэкграунде который будет постоянно чекать сервер на наличие новых сообщений от пользователя, но чувствую в этом глупость кроется, наверно есть по-умнее способ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Советую воспользоваться XMPP протоколом. посмотритье [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/)
Возможно это все серъезные подходы, не то что Вам нужно.. но мало ли.
А так простенький сокет сервер и чат готов.

Comment: OpenFire там уже есть все готовое? там готовые библиотеки с которыми удобно работать или будет трудно разобраться?

Comment: Ну это сервер работающий по протоколу XMPP. Протокол на самом деле толстый, но осилить можно за две недели, если на скиле. А так охватывает все, так работает гуглвоис, фейсбук и пр.
Попробуйте разобраться, как минимум будет актульно и полезно.

Comment: А еще совет личного характера, если боитесь чего-то нового -  берите и изучайте.

Comment: красивые слова

Comment: золотые! не всегда правда позволяют так поступать сроки, но практика показывает что это новое еще не раз встретиться и каждый раз городить велосипед не выход

Comment: это точно, да и чем дольше знаешь больше решений будет.

Comment: на скиле две недели? тогда это серьезно. я скорее всего не на скиле. но попробую все-таки освоить xmpp. хочу сейчас написать кое-что сам, появилась идейка которую пока еще не видел чтоб кто-то реализовал(есть похожее, но не то). по-хорошему, так мне нужно где-то устроится  стажером или джуниором, но почему-то на сердце лежит делать самому что-то.